# Click event not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, event-delegation

I Follow This [Article](http://mrbool.com/creating-a-crud-form-with-html5-local-storage-and-json/26719) for Impalement CRUD Operation with HTML5 and Javascript.

So that Submit Data to [Local Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) and save it.

my problem is Delete and Edit Operation when clicking on delete and edit button    Nothing happens.

**Javascript**

```
$(function () {
  var operation = "A";
  var selected_index = -1;
  var tbClients = localStorage.getItem("tbClients"); //Retrieve the stored data
  tbClients = JSON.parse(tbClients); //Converts string to object
  if (tbClients === null) //If there is no data, initialize an empty array
    tbClients = [];

  function Add() {
    debugger;
    var Data = {
      ExternalProjects: {
        Name: $('#Name').val(),
        Body: $('#Body').val(),
        Url: $('#Url').val()
      }
    };

    tbClients.push(Data);
    localStorage.setItem("tbClients", JSON.stringify(tbClients));
    alert("The data was saved.");
    List();
    return true;
  }

  function Edit() {
    tbClients[selected_index] = JSON.stringify({
      Name: $('#Name').val(),
      Body: $('#Body').val(),
      Url: $('#Url').val()
    }); //Alter the selected item on the table
    localStorage.setItem("tbClients", JSON.stringify(tbClients));
    operation = "A"; //Return to default value
    return true;
  }

  function List() {

    debugger;
    var div = $('div#ExProjectList');
    div.html("");
    var cli = tbClients;
    for (var i = 0; i < cli.length; i++) {
      debugger;
      div.append(
        '<div href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start">' +
        '<div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">' +
        ' <h5 class="mb-1">' + cli[i].ExternalProjects.Name + '</h5>' +
        '  <small>' +
        '<a id="btnDelete"  alt="Delete' + i + '"><i class="fa fa-trash" style="cursor: pointer" ></i></a>' +
        '<a id="btnEdit" alt="Edite' + i + '"><i class="fa fa-pencil" style="cursor: pointer"></i></a>'
        + '</small>' +
        ' </div>' +
        '<p class="mb-1">' + cli[i].ExternalProjects.Body + '</p>' +
        '<small>' + cli[i].ExternalProjects.Url + '</small>' +
        '</div>'
      );
    }
  }

  function Delete() {
    tbClients.splice(selected_index, 1);
    localStorage.setItem("tbClients", JSON.stringify(tbClients));
  } 


  $('#btnDelete').bind('click', function() {
    selected_index = parseInt($(this).attr("alt").replace("Delete", ""));
    Delete();
    List();
  });

  $("#btnEdit").bind("click", function() {
    operation = "E";
    selected_index = parseInt($(this).attr("alt").replace("Edit", ""));
    var cli = JSON.parse(tbClients[selected_index]);
    $("#Name").val(cli.ExternalProjects.Name);
    $("#Body").val(cli.ExternalProjects.Body);
    $("#Url").val(cli.ExternalProjects.Url);
  });




  $("#AddExternalProject").click(function () {
    if (operation === "A"){
      return Add();
    }
    else{
      return Edit();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: My guess is that your page loads and your jQuery runs before those items are loaded into the DOM.

Comment: Any messages in your developer console?

Comment: Edit & Delete buttons are being added dynamically from the `List()` function. You need to use a delegate selector in order to bind click handlers to them. It would look like so: `$("#ExProjectList").on("click", "#btnDelete", function () {...});` and same with `#btnEdit`. Here are the docs for delegate selectors so you can read more about them: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: It's probably also worth mentioning that you are adding the HTML in your `List()` function within a loop, yet the `<a>` tags you are adding have IDs on them - meaning that there is the possibility of duplicate IDs, which leads to bugs very quickly. It would be best that you use classes or data-attributes to identify your `btnDelete` and `btnEdit` elements.

Comment: @Forklift, wrapping your code in `$(function () {...});` ensures that code only runs when the document is ready.

Comment: @Adam Yes, I understand that, but if you follow the execution, nothing calls List(), which means the html elements are not added to the DOM before the click event is attempted to be added to the buttons.

Comment: @lamelemon No, Any Meesage

Comment: @Soheil, nothing calls List() to load those elements before your jQuery runs. This means your click binding code does nothing.

Comment: [Impalement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impalement), huh? ;)

Comment: @mhodges Thank Fixed

Comment: `<div href="#"` is pretty much useless. Only `a` and `link` tags take the `href` attribute and do anything meaningful with it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating the HTML dynamically, but not attaching the event to the element.

Instead of using:

```
$('#btnDelete').bind('click', function() {
    selected_index = parseInt($(this).attr("alt").replace("Delete", ""));
    Delete();
    List();
});


$("#btnEdit").bind("click", function() {
    operation = "E";
    selected_index = parseInt($(this).attr("alt").replace("Edit", ""));
    var cli = JSON.parse(tbClients[selected_index]);
    $("#Name").val(cli.ExternalProjects.Name);
    $("#Body").val(cli.ExternalProjects.Body);
    $("#Url").val(cli.ExternalProjects.Url);
});
```

Use event delegation:

```
$("#ExProjectList").on("click", "#btnDelete", function() {

    selected_index = parseInt($(this).attr("alt").replace("Delete", ""));
    Delete();
    List();
});

$("#ExProjectList").on("click", "#btnEdit", function() {
    operation = "E";
    selected_index = parseInt($(this).attr("alt").replace("Edit", ""));
    var cli = JSON.parse(tbClients[selected_index]);
    $("#Name").val(cli.ExternalProjects.Name);
    $("#Body").val(cli.ExternalProjects.Body);
    $("#Url").val(cli.ExternalProjects.Url);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are binding any event to any html element, always bind inside

> ```
> $(document).ready(function(){
> //code here
> });
> ```

Because if you add the script earlier before Dom Content is ready, in self calling function  then those elements will not be available to bind the events.

Comment: The OP is already binding within `$(function () { ... });` which is the same thing...